# Lazy initialization using functional programming

Tags: java, functional-programming

Let us define a class such that several instance variable must be lazily initialized only once, like this class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Object myLazyField;
    private Integer anotherLazyField;

    public Object getMyLazyField() {
        if (myLazyField == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (myLazyField == null) {
                    myLazyField = new Object();
                }
            }
        }
        return myLazyField;
    }

    public Integer getAnotherLazyField() {
        if (anotherLazyField == null) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (anotherLazyField == null) {
                    anotherLazyField = 10;
                }
            }
        }
        return anotherLazyField;
    }
}
```

The code is quite ugly and the structure of initialization is repetitive.

My question is: **How can I simplify the lazy initialization, to avoid the structure repetition?**

I tried this:

```
class Utility {
    public static <T> T init(Object object, T initialValue, Supplier<T> supplier) {
        synchronized (object) {
            if (initialValue == null) {
                return supplier.get();
            }
        }
        return initialValue;
    }
}
```

and in `MyClass`:

```
 public Object getMyLazyField() {
     if (myLazyField == null) {
         myLazyField = Utility.init(this, myLazyField, Object::new);
     }
     return myLazyField;
 }
```

It's better, but I'm still looking for a better solution using functional programming.

Comment: I don't see why you feel the first solution is ugly. Of course, the duplicate code statements `if (anotherLazyField == null) {` can be removed. Other than that, its just 3 lines of code. Are you trying to generalize lazy initialization of multiple fields?

Comment: I'm not an expert of  Java annotations processing, but I believe you can write a processor that will automatically add laziness to a getter method with proper annotations. Similar to immutables or autovalues.

Comment: @dash-o It's definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I have a `Lazy` class I use a lot on my personal projects. First, usage:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final Lazy<Object> myLazyField = new Lazy<>(Object::new);
    private final Lazy<Integer> anotherLazyField = new Lazy<>(() -> 10);

    public Object getMyLazyField() { return myLazyField.get(); }
    public Integer getAnotherLazyField() { return anotherLazyField.get(); }
}
```

It uses the [double-checked locking idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) you have in your code, with one improvement: the fields are marked `volatile`.<sup>†</sup>

Here's the code:

**Lazy.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

/**
 * A lazy-loaded value that is only created when the value is required. If the
 * value is never used, possibly expensive initialization (either in time or in
 * memory usage) is avoided.
 * <p>
 * This class is thread-safe. Initialization will only ever be performed once,
 * and it is safe to call {@link #get()} simultaneously from different threads.
 * <p>
 * {@code Lazy} makes implementing singletons simple by handling the deferred
 * initialization logic for you. It can also be used as a simple form of caching
 * for expensive computations.
 */
public final class Lazy<T> {
    private volatile T value;
    private volatile Supplier<T> factory;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    /** Create a lazy object that gets its value from the supplied factory. */
    public Lazy(Supplier<T> factory) {
        this.value = null;
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    /**
     * Create a lazy object that holds the given value. This constructor can be
     * used if you happen to have already computed the value.
     */
    public Lazy(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.factory = null;
    }

    /** Get the value. If this is the first call, the value is initialized. */
    public T get() {
        // The double-checked locking idiom is safe in Java when the tested variable is
        // volatile, which `factory` is.
        if (factory != null) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                if (factory != null) {
                    value = factory.get();
                    factory = null;
                }
            }
        }

        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Objects.toString(get());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return (object instanceof Lazy) && Objects.equals(get(), ((Lazy) object).get());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(get());
    }
}
```

---

<sup>†</sup> The Wikipedia article explains why [naïve double-checked locking is unsafe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java):

> Intuitively, this algorithm seems like an efficient solution to the problem. However, this technique has many subtle problems and should usually be avoided. For example, consider the following sequence of events:
>
> 1. Thread A notices that the value is not initialized, so it obtains the lock and begins to initialize the value.
> 2. Due to the semantics of some programming languages, the code generated by the compiler is allowed to update the shared variable to point to a partially constructed object before A has finished performing the initialization. For example, in Java if a call to a constructor has been inlined then the shared variable may immediately be updated once the storage has been allocated but before the inlined constructor initializes the object.
> 3. Thread B notices that the shared variable has been initialized (or so it appears), and returns its value. Because thread B believes the value is already initialized, it does not acquire the lock. If B uses the object before all of the initialization done by A is seen by B (either because A has not finished initializing it or because some of the initialized values in the object have not yet percolated to the memory B uses ([cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence))), the program will likely crash.

Using `volatile` fixes the above problem and makes it safe to use in Java 1.5+.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew about `volatile` trick (IntelliJ complains about missing volatile when running code inspection). I think it's a good idea. My only objection is about the `lock` object: when multiple threads are executing the code, there is the possibility of creating multiple `Lazy` instances and the locking won't be working properly (unless I got something wrong). Can you provide an example how to use it with my code?

Comment: The problem I see is that I have to declare `Lazy` instances as instance variables as you did, I cannot use them as method variables, defined directly in the getter. Aside form that, everything looks fine to me.